# Jquery Validation Form Not Posting

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I've customized my form to validated the required fields but it doesn't submit even though all fields are filled in correctly. From my understanding, the jquery.validate.min.js blocks it from being submitted. Does anyone know why my form doesn't submit?

The code is below:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>


<div>
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="">

<label for="fname">First Name *: </label>
<input id="fname" name="fname">
<br/>
<label for="lname">Last Name *: </label>
<input id="lname" name="lname">
<br/>
<label for="email">Email *: </label>
<input id="email" name="email">
<br/>
<label for="jtitle">Job Title *: </label>
<input id="jtitle" name="jtitle">
<br/>
<label for="orgname">Organization *: </label>
<input id="orgname" name="orgname">
<br/>
<label for="orgname">Describe Yourself *: </label>
<input id="desyourself" name="desyourself" type="hidden" value="123">
<select id="desyourself" name="desyourself">
                    <option value="">
                    Choose One...       </option>
                    <option value="124">
                    Customer
                    </option>
                    <option value="125">
                    Partner
                    </option>
                    <option value="126">
                    Prospect
                    </option>
                    <option value="127">
                    Other
                    </option>
                    <option value="128">
                    Misc.
                    </option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
</div>



<script>
// avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

$.validator.methods.email = function( value, element ) {
  return this.optional( element ) || /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test( value );
}

$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    fname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 30,
        lettersonly: true
    },
    lname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 30,
        lettersonly: true
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    jtitle: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 30
    },
    orgname: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 30
    },
    desyourself: {
        required: true,
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Any java script errors in the console?

Comment: _"why my form doesn't submit?"_  Duplicate `"desyourself"`  `id` and `name` attributes at `input`, `select` elements ? Note, `javascript` is not necessary to return expected results; you can use `HTML5` `required` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Following line is preventing your form to submit:

```
// avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
     debug: true,
     success: "valid"
```

`});`

Answer (score 0):

> debug (default: false) Type: Boolean Enables debug mode. If true, the
>   form is not submitted and certain errors are displayed on the console
>   (will check if a window.console property exists). Try to enable when a
>   form is just submitted instead of validation stopping the submit.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/